# I'm confused about call(), why doesn't my code work?

Tags: javascript, method-call

I'd like to call a function from Mammal, to use with Cat.  I thought I understood it, but every time I try to use it, I get really confused.

```
function Mammal(legs,sound, commonName) {
    this.legs = legs;
    this.sound = sound;
    this.commonName = commonName;
    this.talk = function() {
        console.log(this.sound);
    }
}

const wolf = new Mammal(4, 'GRRRRRR', 'Wolf');

const dog = new Mammal(4, 'WOOF', 'Dog');

console.log(wolf)
console.log(dog.talk())

const cat = function(legs, sound, commonName) {
this.legs = legs;
this.sound = sound;
this.commonName = commonName;
Mammal.call(this, talk)
}

const lion = new cat(4, 'RAWR', 'Lion');
```

I want to use talk, with the context of lion.

Comment: `Mammal.call(this, talk)` calls a function that expects `(legs, sound, commonName)` with the value `talk` (which is a broken reference – there’s nothing called `talk` in scope there). What do you want `Mammal.call(this, talk)` to do?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Are you trying to make `cat.talk()` call the same function as `dog.talk()`?

Answer (score 2):

You were suuuper close. You just need to add the parameters in the Mammal.call() function.

```
function Mammal(legs,sound, commonName) {
    this.legs = legs;
    this.sound = sound;
    this.commonName = commonName;
    this.talk = function() {
        return this.sound;
    }
}

const wolf = new Mammal(4, 'GRRRRRR', 'Wolf');

const dog = new Mammal(4, 'WOOF', 'Dog');

const cat = function(legs, sound, commonName) {
    this.legs = legs;
    this.sound = sound;
    this.commonName = commonName;
    Mammal.call(this, legs, sound, commonName);
}

const lion = new cat(4, 'RAWR', 'Lion');

console.log(lion.talk())
```

I changed Mammal.call(this, talk) to Mammal.call(this, legs, sound, commonName).

I hope this is what you were asking for! Let me know if it isn't.

Edit: I also just noticed that I replaced the console.log() inside of the "talk" function to "return this.sound" and then the very last line I'm doing "console.log(lion.talk())"

Comment: There's no need to perform the 3 assignments before the call, since it's the same thing as the `Mammal` constructor.

Comment: @Barmar There definitely isn't. But it sounds like he's just starting out in javascript and wants to get familiar with random stuff to get the concept down. In this case, its setting variables, I guess? ¯\_(ツ)_/¯  Whatever helps people learn the basics.